# Add Sub list to the custom record

Tags: netsuite

I'm trying to add sublist to the custom record in Netsuite.

Is there any way to add sublist to the custom record?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want the sublist to function. You have the option to create another Custom Record and used the existing as parent record. That will act as a sublist.